How to get a Map of a list from a list of objects in java
I have the following data
[
 {name:a,roll:2,id:3,age:24,city:goa},  
 {name:b,roll:3,id:3,age:24,city:Delhi},  
 {name:c,roll:2,id:1,age:27,city:goa}
]

What I want is
{
   2: [a,c]
   3: [b]
}

I have done the below :
objectList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ObjectRecord::roll))

But this is giving back the list of the fill object:
{
   2: [{name:a,roll:2,id:3,age:24,city:goa},{name:c,roll:2,id:1,age:27,city:goa}]
   3: [{name:b,roll:3,id:3,age:24,city:Delhi}]
}


check the 2-argument groupingBy() documentation and its example
